# std::bitset<N> implementation causes size overheard

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Seems like `std::bitset<N>` under the hood is an array of `unsigned longs` now, this means that there will be an (heavy?) overhead when N is small. `sizeof(std::bitset<8>)` is `8 bytes`!

Is there a reason why the type of underlying array itself is not a `template` parameter? Why does the implementation not use `uint32_t/16_t/8_t` when more appropriate?  I do not see anything in the implementation that limits this?

I am guessing I am missing a particular reason but unsure how to look for it or maybe there is no reason at all ? Since this is such a simple `container` I am not able to understand how the zero overhead principle of `C++` seems to be avoided here.

GCC Impl: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00775_source.html

I believe clang is similar (used sizeof to confirm)

Comment: That's pretty sus tbh. Maybe use `std::array` and do things manually?

Comment: Is this actually a `language-lawyer` question or a specific question on GCC? I don't think the standard requires `unsigned long`s, does it?

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled upon this and I am assuming my knowledge is lacking. @Kostas

Comment: What's a realistic scenario where size would matter for a `std::bitset` with N < 8?  I regularly do embedded work and I cannot conceive of such a scenario.  It doesn't seem worth library implementers' time to optimize for.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 I'm not saying how valid or invalid it is. I'm just wondering why it is the way it is, if there is a reason behind it :)

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde you might be right, I just thought would be better to have it...can remove if you think its inappropriate

Comment: The reason: specializations for small N take developer time and incur risk (even if small).  Almost nobody cares.  Ergo such optimizations are not done.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 hmm not sure if adding a template parameter for this will cause 'risk'. Laziness seems like a more valid reason :)

Comment: Every modification, addition, or subtraction, to software incurs risk.  There is also the opportunity cost of making the changes.  I guarantee you the maintainers are not *lazy*.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 perhaps... would like to hear from someone who maintains this, your guess is as good as mine without it!

Comment: why the downvote? :(

Comment: Adding a template parameter to a standard library class is a _huge_ risk.  You would have to do it in a way that's totally backwards-compatible (likely from both an API and ABI perspective).  It would require a chunk of time from the standards committee to review the proposal and to incorporate the wording into the standard.  Then more time and risk for every standard library implementation to implement the change.  Unless there's some compelling reason for the change I wouldn't expect something like that to happen.

Comment: Well I'm a platform engineer with 20 years experience producing widely used libraries in a variety of languages (some C++ and some templated) so I like kind of know what I'm talking about.  But yeah your guess is good too I bet they're just lazy.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53  I'm sure your platform software is great but your answer was not :) Miles' answer makes sense though!

Comment: Using a longer type will make the code use less elements, which will simplify array lookup. For the typical use-cases using the longest word-length will mean there's no lookup at all (zero overhead). It will simplify things in the long run. So it's the usual tradeoff between simplicity, speed and space.

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @tumble well, naively you could go `bitset<7> arr[1024]` or somesuch, which with this implementation would be disasterous.

Comment: By the way, if you want to reference an implentation, please pick something a little more modern than the *ancient* GCC version 4.6. Especially considering you've tagged C++17 which is implemented much later.

Comment: @miles you'd add it to the base class and compress the storage, not in the derived I suspect.  It would be an ABI break due to size differences, but not a huge risk otherwise.  You could not add it to std bitset itself for many reasons, of course.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, finally a comment that makes sense.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont but you can do disastrous things all over the place so I am not sure if that is the ONLY reason :) but yeah I didnt think of that at all

Comment: @pya I mean, if you copy to bitset and back for small stuff, you should be good; byte level bit operations often suck compared to machine word level ones.  Barring storage, this seems like a non issue to me.  And for small collections, you can just convert to/from bitset.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont got it :) thanks! I was just wondering why it was decided to be implemented this way which makes sense now -> `byte level bit operations often suck compared to machine word level ones`

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to understand how the zero overhead principle of C++ seems to be avoided here.

The zero-overhead principle is a *principle*, not an absolute rule of C++.

Many people use `std::vector` in contexts where a compile-time fixed capacity would be useful. Such a type could have only two pointers instead of three and thus be 50% smaller. Many people use `std::string` in contexts where an immutable string would work just as well if not better; it would reduce the size of the string (ignoring SSO), as well as its complexity. And so forth.

These all represent inefficiencies relative to the standard type. No standard library type can handle every possible usage scenario. The goal for such types is to be broadly useful, not perfect.

There is nothing preventing someone from writing a bitset-style type with the exact same interface which has a user-provided underlying type. But the standard has no such type.

Indeed, there's nothing preventing *implementations* of `bitset` from choosing an underlying type based on the given number of bits. Your implementation doesn't do that, but it could have.

Comment: Makes sense, I was not sure if there is a particular reason why `unsigned long` was the defacto. Seems like there is not. Thanks!